# ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy is empty before saving and reloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm curious why my `has_many :through` association is not populated until after my object is saved and reloaded. It seems like all the data should be there for the joins to be constructed.

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140821223311) do
  create_table "cats", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "human_id"
  end
  create_table "houses", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "address"
  end
  create_table "humen", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "house_id"
  end
end
```

Models:

```
class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :human, inverse_of: :cats
  has_one :house, through: :human
  has_many(
    :siblings,
    through: :house,
    source: :cats
  )
end
class Human < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cats, inverse_of: :human
  belongs_to :house, inverse_of: :humans
end
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :humans, inverse_of: :house
  has_many :cats, through: :humans
end
```

I've saved an instance of House and Human in the db. The seed file looks like this:

```
h = House.create(address: "123 Main")
Human.create(house_id: h.id, name: "stu")
```

I've been testing with this:

```
c = Cat.new(human_id: 1, name: "something awesome")
p c.siblings # => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
c.save
p c.siblings # => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
c.reload
p c.siblings # => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Cat id: 2, name: "gizmo", created_at: "2014-08-21 22:37:07", updated_at: "2014-08-21 22:37:07", human_id: 1>]>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated :)

here's a github repo if you want to play with it:
https://github.com/w1zeman1p/association_wat

Answer (score 0):

It seems CollectionProxy is a bit too lazy. If you do:

```
c = Cat.new(human_id: 1, name: "something awesome")
c.save
c.siblings
```

You get what you expect.

So it might be the CollectionProxy being cached from your first call to `.siblings` before the cat is saved.

Comment: I think you're right and it is getting cached, however I'm interested in potentially using that association as part of a validation. So it would be nice to have it available even before saving. Which doesn't seem unreasonable right? - PS nice to hear from you @peter :)